# Java atomic lazySet

Tags: java, atomic

Suppose I have an `AtomicInteger` value, `ai`. In thread `T1`, I do:

```
x = 42         // x is a non-volatile shared integer
ai.lazySet(0);
```

AFAIK, in another thread *if* `ai.get()` returns `0`, the write `x=42` will also be visible.

Now, in another thread T2 (after T1 is run), I do:

```
ai.lazySet(1);
```

Will setting `x=42` from `T1` be visible after this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reading of this is that: If, in T2, ai.get() returns 0 before you call ai.lazySet(1), then the x=42 write will also be visible in T2.

This is the transitivity property of happens-before from the JMM.

I don't think you can get any stronger guarantees than that from the JMM. However, in practice, real JVMs may do better.

Answer (score 0):

Quick correction to above: lazySet is not part of the JMM. It's a late addition to the JDK an is a documented feature, but as of yet has not made it into the official JMM. You can read more about where is came from here: http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/atomiclazyset-is-performance-win-for.html

The happens before guarantee is there for T1, i.e any write made by T1 before calling lazySet will be visible when the value 0 is visible, they cannot be re-ordered.

T2 calling lazySet will have the same guarantee to writes made in T2.

There are no guarantees as to when T2 will see the value written by T1 and vice-versa, although in practice they will see the values fairly quickly(or so Doug Lea claims anyway). And indeed experimentation show the latency to be similar to that of a volatile write(see the link for an experiment and results).